# Page cannot be displayed when accessing Report Server in another computer

Tags: reporting-services, reportserver

I have set up a Report Server in a Windows 10 client, everything is fine when you try to access it locally, but when I try to access it using another computer, "This page can't be displayed" is the only result that I get. I can ping the computer where the report server is installed, firewall has been set up, tried different authentication but still the same result.

EDIT:

Below is the logfile of my SSRS

```
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: EventPolling polling service started
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: NotificationPolling polling service started
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: SchedulePolling polling service started
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: UpgradePolling polling service started
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: PollingMaintenance: Polling started
rpcserver!DefaultDomain!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: RPC Server started.
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: RPC Server started. Endpoint name ='ReportingServices$MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER'
appdomainmanager!WindowsService_0!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:52:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 WindowsService_0 initialized.
library!DefaultDomain!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:07:53:: i INFO: Catalog SQL Server Edition = Developer
library!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:12:36:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database.;
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:12:36:: e ERROR: PollingFunction: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: An error occurred within the report server database.  This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.).
rpcserver!DefaultDomain!1d90!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: Process monitoring stopped.
rpcserver!DefaultDomain!2248!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: RPC Server stopped.
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!2248!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: RPC Server stopped. 
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2248!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 WindowsService_0 unregistered.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!2248!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 WindowsService_0 unloading.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1ff0!07/17/2019-10:12:44:: i INFO: AppDomain:2 0 pending unload(s)
servicecontroller!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: Service controller exiting.
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: PollingFunction: Exiting for the following exception: Thread was being aborted.
dbpolling!WindowsService_0!bc8!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: PollingMaintenance: Exiting for the following exception: Thread was being aborted.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!c44!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: Appdomain:2 unregistered.
rshost!rshost!c44!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: Application domain type WindowsService statistics: created: 1, unloaded: 1, failed: 0, timed out: 0.
servicecontroller!DefaultDomain!2248!07/17/2019-10:12:46:: i INFO: Service shutting down.
```

Comment: Can you post screenshot

Comment: screenshot of the webpage?

Comment: check the reporting services configuration manager. Look in the "web portal URL" tab and that should show you the URL to access the report.

Comment: @AlanSchofield yes, I did that, but to no avail, the other computer still can't access the report server